# Degree of a projected curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I cannot find the proof of the following fact, can anyone help me?

> Let $C$ be a projective curve in $\mathbb P^n$ and $p\in C$ a smooth point. Let $C'$ be the closure in $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ of the image of $C\setminus p$ via the projection from $p$. Prove that $\deg C' = \deg C-1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Think about a generic hyperplane through $p$; it projects to a generic hyperplane in $\mathbf P^{n-1}$. Can you count the number of intersection points of the latter with $C'$?

Comment: I think we can assume p=[1,0]

Comment: I think we can assume p=[1,0...,0] and take the projection to the hyperplane S defined by x_0=0. Choosing then a hyperplane H in P^n such that, if d is the degree of C, and C, H meets in p and in other (d-1) points belonging to S we can obtain the result, but what guarantees that the number of points of intersection obtained in the projection is the maximal one, i.e. it is the degree of C'? And is it possibile to choose such a H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one could argue as follows: Let $W$ be the variety of hyperplanes through $p \in C$. Then $\dim W = n-1$. Now for an arbitrary curve $D \subset \mathbf{P}^n$ consider the subset $\Gamma \subseteq D \times W$ defined by

$$\Gamma = \{ (x,H) \in D \times W \mid H \text{ tangential to } D \text{ at } x\}$$

Then the fiber over $x \in D$ of $\Gamma \to D$ has dimension $n-3$, therefore $\dim \Gamma = n-2$. As $\dim W = n-1$ the image of $\Gamma$ in $W$ has an open complement. Now let $D$ be first $C'$ giving $\Gamma_0=\Gamma_{C'}$.
Next let $D$ be $C - \{p\}$ giving $\Gamma_1$. Take $\Gamma_{11} = \bar{\Gamma_1}$, the closure of $\Gamma_1$ in $C \times W$. Additionally let $\Gamma_2$ be the subset of $W$ consisting of hyperplanes $H$ tangential to $C$ at $p$. Then $\dim \Gamma_0 = \dim \Gamma_{11} = \dim \Gamma_2 = n-2$.
So the complement of the image of the union of these three varieties in $W$ is an open set in $W$.
It consists of hyperplanes $H$ which are transversal to $C$ and $C'$ everywhere and so furnish a proof of the assertion. Of course $n$ must be greater than $2$.

Comment: Ok, your construction is clear, but Il do not understand how you found the dimensions of the fiber over x.

Comment: The fiber over $x$ consists of hyperplanes, that go through $p$ (first condition), go through $x$ (second condition), contain the tangent line of $D$ at $x$ (third condition) (instead of "containing the tangent line" one could think of "containing an infinitely near point to $x$"). So we have three independent conditions on a hyperplane with $n$ degrees of freedom, giving dimension $n-3$ for the fiber.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear.  thank you!