# Degree of $\pi_p(C)$, where $\pi_p$ is the projection from $p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, riemann-surfaces, projective-space

Consider the rational projection map from a point $p$, $\pi_p:\mathbb{P}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ given by sending $q\neq p$ to the intersection of the line containing $q,p$ with $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, and sending $p$ to $\infty$. Consider the image $\pi_p(C)$ for some curve $C\subset \mathbb{P}^n$.

I am trying to determine the bound $\deg(\pi_p(C))\leq \deg(C)-1$.

How does one go about this?

Edit: the map $\pi_p$ is not defined at $p$ (see @Kreiser's comment below)

Comment: 1. $p$ is not sent to $\infty$. The map $\pi_p$ is simply not defined at $p$. 2. Do you know the generalized Bezout theorem?

Comment: @KReiser A rational map on a non-singular curve with target proper always extends to a regular morphism (see Hartshorne I.6.8).

Comment: @AGlearner yes, but $\pi_p$ is defined from $\Bbb P^n$ in the post and there is legitimately no way to pick somewhere to send $p$ when discussing the rational map $\pi_p:\Bbb P^n\dashedrightarrow\Bbb P^{n-1}$.

Comment: @KReiser Well, choose a sequence $\{p_k\}$ goes to $p$ on $C$, $\pi_p(p_k)$ has a limit in $\mathbb P^{n-1}$. That's the implication of the Proposition that I cited.

Comment: @AGlearner I am well aware of this proposition and how one works with these things. I was merely pointing out that ***as written in the post*** the statement that "$\pi_p$... send[s] $p$ to $\infty$" is not correct.

Comment: @KReiser To me, there is no problem to say "sends $p$ to $\infty$" if OP specify the domain is (nonsingular) curve.

Comment: @KReiser I do know of it but am not well-versed. How else could it be applied here other than to show that the intersection between the line and $\mathbb{P}^{n−1}$ is at a point?

Comment: @AGlearner My entire point was that as stated in the OP, the domain is $\Bbb P^n$ (not $C$) and one cannot define the image of $p$ considering $\pi_p$ as a map from $\Bbb P^n$. Now please, let us stop this derail.

Comment: @JonDoe Pick a hyperplane through $p$ which intersects your curve in $\deg C-1$ other points (this is where you use generalized Bezout: to get the number of intersections). Now consider how the projection of the hyperplane intersects the projection of the curve, count points, and apply Bezout again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $n\ge 3$, so the target is not $\mathbb P^1$ and $\pi_p|_C:C\to \pi_p(C)$ is birational.

Choose a general hyperplane $H\subseteq \mathbb P^{n-1}$ that intersects $\pi_p(C)$ transversely at $m$ points. So
$$\deg(\pi_p(C))=\#(H\cap \pi_p(C))=m.$$

Now, the cone of $H$ and $p$ defines a hyperplane $\tilde{H}$ of $\mathbb P^{n}$, which intersects $C$ at the preimages of those $m$ points plus a point $p$. By generality, all intersections are simple, so

$$\deg(C)=\#(\tilde{H}\cap C)=1+\deg(\pi_p(C)).$$

Comment: For a proof of generality, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419988/degree-of-a-projected-curve).